# Electrum Wallet: zero mBTC balance after sweeping private address

Tags: electrum, paper-wallet, private-key-import, sweep

Have the newest (3.+) ver. of Electrum Wallet.  I performed the sweep of the private address to acquire BTC from paper wallet . 
Wallet menu->Private Keys-> Sweep.  Performed the operation, the screen showed me the entire amount in the paper wallet minus (I assume) transaction fees.

It's been about 12 hrs since sweep, the Electrum shows **0 mBTC balance**, **History is empty** (I checked all addresses generated by Electrum W).  What advice would you have how to proceed from here and check where the funds are?   Electrum W. has rather non-intuitive manual and all the functions I try are giving me no response w.r.t. any incoming funds .

Comment: What value do you see for blockchain under tools > network > first tab?

Answer (score 0):

obv i would check the paper wallet address to make sure it is empty.

if it is, then i would input the tx id or the btc address into Blockchain and see what's up.
if you swept it correctly, then the funds are there somewhere.

also, if the amount swept was a lot and your fee was puny, be prepared to wait a very long time.

i see SO MANY NOOBS try to transact 5/10/40 btcs at once and pay a fee of $3!!!!!
not saying you did that....just saying

Comment: My case is simple:  one (1) transaction and 2 BTC level.  Have to follow all the operations on BlockChain.

Comment: And last comment:  This is my first experience with Electrum W. - and according to manual - the fees are adjusted dynamically. So I went  the default.

Comment: if the wallet lets you adjust it id go 1 level higher than default just because of the craziness of btc right now. the fee is determined by the byte size of the trx just so you know. (i guess i wasnt being clear with that on other ?s so just letting you know bro). And yes, follow all ops on Blockchain.info. gl bud....

Comment: The one transaction to sweep all funds has to include the inputs for all payments you ever made to your paper wallet. If you made twenty different payments into your paper wallet over time then the transaction that you made has twenty inputs.